# Excel IF any cells is Y then all other cells are N

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some advise on an excel formula.
I have 6 cells (A1 to A6) - If ANY of them is "Y" then I want all the others to auto populate to "N".
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have tried =IF(OR(H2 = "Y",J2 = "Y", K2 = "Y", L2="Y", M2= "Y"),"N", "") just hoped there may be an easier / better way.

Comment: Using formula you can only change the value of cell in which the formula resides. You cannot change the value of some other cell using formula, you'll have to use VBA.

Comment: I understand that, but I was hoping there is some formula I could easily reuse in all cells.

Comment: As I said, formula will not work as you want to change values in other cells also.

Comment: Are you interested in VBA solution?

Comment: Mrig, yes I can try but I have never done VBA before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A6")    'set rng as A1:A6
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:A6")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If UCase(Target) = "Y" Then 'check if entered value is Y
            rng.Value = "N"         'make cells N
            Target = "Y"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Insert VBA code to Excel Workbook**

1. Open your workbook in Excel.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open *Microsoft Visual Basic Editor*.
3. At the top left corner of the editor window, under *Project-VBAProject* pane, double click on the sheet name you want code to work for.
4. Copy above VBA code and paste it to the right pane of the VBA editor.
5. Finally, change the values in `Range A1:A6` and you should get desired result.

To know how to enter this code in workbook see [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm).